# Erratic Subplot Axes Appearance when Ploting

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, subplot

I am having several axes on a same plot, all divided with subplots:

```
%% Stage 1
figure(13);
set(gcf,'Position',[60 30 1400 720]);
ha(1)=subplot(5,3,[1 2 4 5 7 8]);  % Top-left
ha(2)=subplot(5,3,[3 6 9]);        % Top-right
ha(3)=subplot(5,3,[10 11]);        % Middle-left
ha(4)=subplot(5,3,[12]);           % Middle-right
ha(5)=subplot(5,3,[13 14]);        % Bottom-left
ha(6)=subplot(5,3,[15]);           % Bottom-right
```

Then i am using each subplot immediately, i.e. for the fourth middle-right subplot axes:

```
%% Stage 2.4
axes(ha(4)); plot(Mi(4).t,Mi(4).x);
```

Stage 1 looks like this (See first attached image).

Stage 2.4 looks like this (see second attached image), thus ruining all the presentation, changing the appearance of the fourth and sixth subplot axes. Why this happens? How should i solve this???!!...

All x ranges are equal (dates). All equally arranged y ranges -i.e. Top with Top, Middle with Middle- are equal (scaled values). Note that this disarrangement kills this order.

Thanks in advance,...

Stage 1 with correct subplot appearance:
[image: Stage 1 with correct subplot appearance]

Stage 2 4 with wrong subplot appearance on the 4 and the 6:
[image: Stage 2 4 with wrong subplot appearance]

Edit No.1:
If adjusting axis before plotting:
[image: Trial with wrong subplot appearance]

Comment: have you tried to set the axes limits in advance? If everything is fixed in advance and just the data is missing, it should work.

Comment: This is great!... I did it. Changed the axis before plotting, to the exact, final values both on x and y axis. Look at the Attachment 3. It failed... :/

Comment: I think we need you data to help you further, to completely reproduce your problem. Or examplified data, where you experience the same misbehavior.

Comment: I rechecked the code with the above answer, and the 'get' 'set' properties proved to be ok. THANKS also....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed very frustrating. It seems like it only resizes the subplot if it is an 1x1 subplot  that is not on the lower row, (i.e. `subplot(3,1,1)`, is resized to accommodate for x-axis magnitude label (10^7? - as you indicated not x-label!), but not `subplot(3,1,1:2)` or `subplot(3,1,3)`). For example, consider the following to code bits, with the example data:

```
Mi(4).t = 1:100:1e7;
Mi(4).x = randn(size(Mi(4).t));
```

Option #1 (using `get` and `set`):

```
figure(14);
set(gcf,'Position',[60 30 1400 720]);
ha(1)=subplot(5,3,[1 2 4 5 7 8]);  % Top-left
ha(2)=subplot(5,3,[3 6 9]);        % Top-right
ha(3)=subplot(5,3,[10 11]);        % Middle-left
ha(4)=subplot(5,3,[12]);           % Middle-right
ha(5)=subplot(5,3,[13 14]);        % Bottom-left
ha(6)=subplot(5,3,[15]);           % Bottom-right

hapos=get(ha,'Position');
axes(ha(4)); plot(Mi(4).t,Mi(4).x);
for sp = 1:length(hapos)
    set(ha(sp),'Position',hapos{sp});
end
```

Option #2 (using no single subplots to support my earlier point):

```
figure(15);
set(gcf,'Position',[60 30 1400 720]);
ha(1)=subplot(10,3,[1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16 17]);  % Top-left
ha(2)=subplot(10,3,[3 6 9 12 15 18]);        % Top-right
ha(3)=subplot(10,3,[19 20 22 23]);        % Middle-left
ha(4)=subplot(10,3,[21 24]);           % Middle-right
ha(5)=subplot(10,3,[25 26 28 29]);        % Bottom-left
ha(6)=subplot(10,3,[27 30]);           % Bottom-right
axes(ha(4)); plot(Mi(4).t,Mi(4).x);
```

You may want to actually adjust the subplot positions to make space for your x-axis magnitude label.

Comment: 1.- Ive changed the code and added the `set` `get` trick, after and before the plotting. No results at all!!... 2.- Note there are not x-labels neither. Matlab symply wishes to readjust freely the subplots, just the unknown way he wants... 3.- Ive tried running only the 4th. It DOES changes the axis presentation... :/

Comment: Thanks by the answer and all your kind suggestions, by the way :)

Comment: @hypfco, I've updated the answer, but the code essentially is the same. If I run the code above I get the wanted effect, with no resizing. Make sure that with the `get` `set` commands you call it after you have done any operations to the subplot, such as color bars, axis labels or such. Thanks for pointing out you don't have x-labels. I was referring to the 10^7(?) that is part of your x-ticks, and got mixed-up myself. Please run the code above without any other code that you haven't given and see if it does what you intend it to. If not, please let me know with what additional code it fails.

Comment: I've rechecked the code. 'set' and 'get' original and final settings are correctly shown after the reordering. THANKS....